# Web Browser Control Script Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am creating an Access 2010 form with a web browser that contains the weather data.  I am getting a script error during run time of: "Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'".  I am still able to use the web browser and the form but this error is just a nuisance since the user will have to clear it every time the form loads.  This error seems to be related to the share option button on the web page which doesn't seem to be supported by Access 2010.

Is there a way around this error.  I added the vba code

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
```

on the form and subform during Events OnLoad and After Update, but this didn't ignore the warning.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  I used the following VBA code to suppress the errors:

```
Me.MyWebBrowser.Object.Silent = True
```